# pause or freezing game screen

Tags: java, android, libgdx, savegame

I have a question regarding the pausing/freezing a game while a window/pausemenu will appear at center of the screen. I've already created a pausescreen class which will be called each time the back key is being pressed.

My problem is that I don't know how to freeze or put the game to pause, this becomes a problem because whenever i tried to click on the outsides of the pause window the player could move around.

Comment: Basically, inside your game loop you need to check if you are in pause mode, and if so, don't handle input (except for your pause menu of course) and don't update the world.

Comment: The pause function in a game is a typical use case for the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern. Whether you implement a pause function as multiple gamestates, e.g. one for ingame, one for pause, or just a single boolean flag indicating the pause being toogled is up to you.

Comment: correct if im wrong dear sirs. I have declared state as int and for my gamestates i have declared gamepaused = 0, and gameunpause=1. after this i've create an two methods. updaterunning which will all my rendering and controls while updatepaused will contain my setscreen for pausewindow to show. is this correct?the problem that i have encountered here is that my gamescreen still doesn't freeze while my pause window is visible.

Comment: Are you using canvas or openGL? How about some code?